# Video editing using pixels matrix

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

This is a beginner question, please warn me if this is not the most appropriate forum for it.

I'm willing to write a video editing program just out of curiosity, but I've never done video editing before and I have very small experience with image editing, just using the built-in features of GitHub. Also, I have very small experience with programming, just intermediate C++ (besides drawing with Metapost; I'm from Geometry).

My idea is to edit the video frame by frame, so that each frame can be treated as an image. Each image should be translated into a pixels matrix, with values in some colour space. Then I will be able to apply a certain mathematical transformation I have in mind to this matrix, translate it back into an image and build up the video again from the obtained frames. The mathematical transformation shall be depend on the frame and on a random variable, but fortunately it can still be applied frame by frame, i.e. it won't be necessary to recall the entire video in order to so (or more precisely, just the transformation applied to the previous frame, for the sake of some sort of 'continuity of randomness').

The mathematical transformation is the easy part, I already have the algorithm sketched and it's not complicate at all... It can be easily written using C++, provided the pixels matrix is given. Possibly, the only detail I'll have to figure out is that this algorithm will necessarily increase the image size, so some related data shall be modified as well, but nothing to worry about, I believe.

- I'd like to know: what paths do you recommend for me to implement
  that project? Softwares, codes, languages... Anything might be
  helpful.

I've tried to look for something related to the  image editing part of the project, but I felt that the need of editing a video instead of an isolated image would make it useless to explore this part more deeply before knowing the path I've chosen will be lead to my aim. That's why I decided to ask for help here before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: OpenCV will allow you to extract frames from a video stream and later create a new stream from the modified images. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: Wow! At a first glance, that's exactly what I was looking for. =]

Comment: hate to do it but this is literally asking to be recommended libraries. please review [ask]. -- the distinction between "images" and "matrices/arrays" is practically not made. everyone uses numpy in python, except for specific use cases where PIL Image objects need to carry additional metadata. -- besides OpenCV, there's `imageio`, and if you need complete control over the decoding and encoding, there is PyAV. -- `skimage` is another popular library for image manipulation.

Comment: oh, highgui would be the right start, because you can just `imshow` what effect you just made, no need to write a video file. and if the effect doesn't need any input, you don't even need to read a file. -- and switch the docs to 4.x or so because 2.x has been EOL for a few years now

Comment: _"...Write a video editing program just out of curiosity"_ If you use Chrome browser, you can encode/decode H264 via its **webCodecs** API. That gives you the raw H264 frames... You can learn about MP4 container format (for some edits like: trim, frame rate adjust, video rotation, etc) and write such bytes in Javascript... In JS there is also a Canvas object to edit the pixels of a frame. You can run C++ code in browser via the **WASM** (Web Assembly) API though it might be re-creatable in JS, where there is also GPU access if you are willing to write the code.